# how to replace a date column of a dataframe with a random date between two dates in python

Tags: python

Please help me in replacing a date column of a data frame with random dates between two date (2020-10-01 & 2020-10-31). Below is the sample data for your reference:

```
stocks = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'ticker':np.repeat( ['aapl','goog','yhoo','msft'], 25 ),
    'date':np.tile( pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=25, freq='D'), 4 ),
    'price':(np.random.randn(100).cumsum() + 10) })
```

I have tried the below code. However i am not able to implement the code in a dataframe level.

```
import time
import datetime
import numpy as np

n_rows = 30

start_time = "01/11/2020"
end_time = "30/11/2020"

date2int = lambda s: time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s,"%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
int2date = lambda s: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

start_time = date2int(start_time)
end_time = date2int(end_time)

random_ints = np.random.randint(low=start_time, high=end_time, size=(n_rows,1))
random_dates = np.apply_along_axis(int2date, 1, random_ints).reshape(n_rows,1)

print (random_dates)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pd.Timestamp and random.randint to generate random dates between given dates and use pd.to_datetime() to convert it to date

```py
start = '2020-10-01' # Specify start date
end = '2020-10-31'
n = len(stocks)
x = np.random.randint(pd.Timestamp(start).value, pd.Timestamp(end).value,n, dtype=np.int64)
stocks['date'] = [pd.to_datetime((i/10**9)/(60*60)/24, unit='D').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')  for i in x]
```

Comment: ValueError: high is out of bounds for int32

Comment: I have updated my answer, is there still problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code to get random dates:

```
from datetime import datetime
import random

def random_date(first_date, second_date):
    first_timestamp = int(first_date.timestamp())
    second_timestamp = int(second_date.timestamp())
    random_timestamp = random.randint(first_timestamp, second_timestamp)
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(random_timestamp)

d1 = datetime.strptime("01/11/2020", "%d/%m/%Y")
d2 = datetime.strptime("30/11/2020", "%d/%m/%Y")

print (random_date(d1, d2))
```

This will give you random dates:

```
2020-11-05 01:16:31
```

Are you trying to create a dataframe with n number of dates ?

If yes, then this will help you create the random dates in your `stocks` dataframe.

```
stocks = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'ticker':np.repeat( ['aapl','goog','yhoo','msft'], 25 )
    ,'date':[random_date(d1, d2) for _ in range(100)]
    ,'price':(np.random.randn(100).cumsum() + 10) 
    })
    
print (stocks)
```

The output will be:

```
ticker                date      price
0    aapl 2020-11-19 09:55:04  10.237543
1    aapl 2020-11-25 13:43:08  11.114540
2    aapl 2020-11-24 07:37:50  11.545754
3    aapl 2020-11-18 16:37:05  11.922486
4    aapl 2020-11-04 15:13:12  11.939903
..    ...                 ...        ...
95   msft 2020-11-27 19:14:59  13.909287
96   msft 2020-11-01 11:25:28  13.636019
97   msft 2020-11-03 14:29:13  13.620961
98   msft 2020-11-22 22:37:58  14.943541
99   msft 2020-11-10 19:31:35  15.180015

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: the objective is to replace the existing date column and apply a random date. Lets say between two date (start = '2020-10-01' & end = '2020-10-31')